# How to get sum value from one to many relationship tables?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables `task` and `task_detail` with one to many relationship. Tables  are illustrated below.

I just want all the task data and sum of amount from task_detail where task_id is equals to task's id. I have tried some queries but noone seems to work fine for me.

```
SELECT t.*, td.amount AS amount FROM task AS t 
LEFT JOIN task_detail AS td ON t.emp_id=td.emp_id  WHERE t.emp_id=52
```

Is there any way to get that?

[image]

Comment: `SUM(td.amount) AS amount`

Comment: But it gives data in single records..

Comment: give sample output so you can get proper answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want get SUM of amount for each task of 52 employee? Then you can do it using below query. If not, please explain in detail.

```
SELECT task_id, SUM(amount)
FROM task_detail
WHERE emp_id = 52
GROUP BY task_id
```

If you want to get task's another columns, you can use this:

```
SELECT t.*, td.amt
FROM task AS t 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT task_id, SUM(amount) AS amt
        FROM task_detail
        WHERE emp_id = 52
        GROUP BY task_id
    ) AS td ON t.task_id = td.task_id
WHERE t.emp_id = 52
```

Comment: Worked for me. I was missing GROUP BY which resulted in single record. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use SUM or Group by

```
SELECT SUM(td.amount) AS amount
FROM task AS t
LEFT JOIN task_detail AS td ON t.emp_id = td.emp_id
WHERE t.emp_id = 52
Group by task_id
```

Answer (score 0):

use of aggregate function, with group by clause is mandatory, as mentioned first answer it will not give sum

```
          select t1.firstname, sum(t2.amount) as 'total', t1.taskID  
          from tasks t1 join task_Details t2 
          on t1.UserID = t2.UserId
          where t1.UserID = 3
          group by t1.firstname, t1.taskID
```

Comment: you can give conditional where clause as that I have shown for userid i.e. task id